# Completely hide windows taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar

Recently i've created a setup with a huge oled display and after using solid black as background and hiding windows taskbar the i can still see a small few pixel high taskbar (while its hidden).

I understand it maybe is done to indicate that there is something there, but is it possible to completely hide it? trough cmd or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free [Taskbar Activate version 2.4](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Taskbar-Activate.shtml) by Pierre-Marie Devigne is an old (1999!) application that works well, *at least* through Windows 10, that has a setting to completely hide the taskbar until mouse hovers over it. See if that cleans up the screen. That app also provides an adjustable delay to prevent accidental taskbar popup.

[image: Taskbar Activate]

Comment: thank you sir, its amazing that something from 1999 is working for windows 11 :D
does the job, nothing less nothing more